# JSONP isn't returning data in https

Tags: asp.net, json, https, jsonp

I spent all Friday on this, and figured I'd come in on Monday and see if I can get some help.  Here's a summary:

I have two websites, one uses AJAX to call at http handler on another website to get a token (string) back.  I initially used a json call which works great, but when the site I'm accessing uses https, the data isn't returned.

I get a 200 success message back, and I get data back using http, but not https.  I am having this issue working on my local machine.  I verify that if I use the same URL, data is returned in my browser.

Also, when in https mode, I set a breakpoint and it looks like it doesn't even call the code to pass back the token.

Thanks in Advance!

```
         function onSuccessGetToken(token, url, type) {
         var getTokenUrl = url + "SSOtoken=" + token;

         //verify the URL is correct, for testing
         alert(getTokenUrl);

         $.ajax({
             url: getTokenUrl,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 onSuccess(JSON.stringify(msg).replace(/\"/g, ""), url, type);
             },
             error: function (msg) {
                 //using jsonp, this always goes here, but no data is returned
                 alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
                 onErrorGetToken(msg);
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: JSONP and JSON are two entirely different things. Your question title talks about JSONP, but I'm pretty sure you're really talking about JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown what `getTokenUrl` contains, but from your problem description I'd say you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents ajax calls between different "origins." Note "origin" does not mean "domain", different domains are different origins, but so are different protocols (`http` vs. `https`), different ports (`80` vs. `8080` for instance), etc.

In your question, you talk about JSONP, but you're not using JSONP. You *can* use JSONP to handle cross-origin requests, that's what it's for. To do that, use `"jsonp"` as your `dataType` and make sure your server returns a correct JSONP response (including getting the name of the JSONP callback from the query string). More about JSONP in [the Wikipedia article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Another strategy for doing cross-origin calls when you control both origins is to use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). This is where your server responds to a "preflight" request the browser sends which tells the browser whether the server will accept a call from the document's origin. [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) for it is pretty good these days outside of IE. In IE9 and earlier, it's supported, by not via the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object (which is what jQuery uses). As of IE10, they finally get it right.

---

Unrelated: Your `ajax` call, you're specifying `contentType: "application/json"`. That's telling the server that what you're **sending** is JSON, not telling jQuery to treat the *response* as JSON. That's the other one, `dataType`, which you're also specifying (although with a properly-configured server, you shouldn't have to — the server should return the `Content-Type` header with the correct MIME type).

Comment: getTokenUrl works correctly, I do an alert and can verify it's working in http or https mode.  Your comment about the Same Origin Policy, I thought it had to do with domain, but you may be correct with the port, I'll try to run my site in https mode and see if that helps.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I simply used https on both sites and it works.  Can't believe I wasted an entire Friday on something that simple.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @dave2118: You're welcome! Glad that helped. Yeah, some browsers are pretty subtle about SOP reporting. FWIW, if you were using Chrome and looked in the developer tools, it has a fairly clear error message about it (nowadays, it didn't always). I don't know about other browsers...

Comment: We use IE internally, so I haven't really used Chrome since it wasn't required, but thank you for the tip.